# Работа с файлами большого объема C#

Tags: c#, файлы, csv

Есть скаченный csv файл объемом 1,5 гигабайта. В нем содержится примерно 120 000 000 строк в формате xxxx,yyyyyy. Из них 100 000 это кривые строки с артефактами, эти строки всегда меньше 11 символов.

Задача состоит следующая: обработать файл, и записать правильные строки в новый csv файл. Код, который я написал, отрабатывает эту операцию примерно за 10 часов.

Можно ли эту процедуру по времени сократить?

```
string line;
using (var file = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:\bzip2\decompressed.csv")))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if( line.Length == 11 )
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"D:\bzip2\new.csv", line + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если использовать `StreamWriter` результат тот же?

Comment: 1) Попробуйте использовать другой конструктор, содержащий bufferSize, задайте bufferSize = 32768. Если в с# грамотно сделана буферизация - сработает. 2) вы работаете с строками. Строки очень нагружают процесс, перейдите на работу с байтами - это ускорит процесс, но заберёт у вас пару дней.

Comment: @dgzargo StreamWriter действительно решил проблему. Файл создается за пару минут. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте с буфером, пишите с буфером, и всё будет хорошо

```
string line;
using (var file = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(@"D:\bzip2\decompressed.csv"), 10*1024*1024)))
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(@"D:\bzip2\new.csv"), 10*1024*1024)))
{       
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Length == 11)          
            writer.WriteLine(line);

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как предложили выше надо было вместо File.AppendAllText использовать StreamWriter. С буфером тоже работает быстро. Файл создается около 2-5 минут. Теперь осталось понять как работает Stream и File чтобы разобраться в причине.

Comment: @AndreySherman Причину низкой производительности уже написали ответом ниже: `Этот метод каждый раз будет открывать файл, перемещать указатель в его конец, дописывать текст и закрывать файл.`

Comment: @AndreySherman у вас было 2 причины тормозов: 1) Чтение и запись без буфера 2) Открытие, закрытие и перемещение к концу выходного файла на каждую строку

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего низкая скорость связана с вызовом `File.AppendAllText`. Этот метод каждый раз будет открывать файл, перемещать указатель в его конец, дописывать текст и закрывать файл.

Все операции, кроме дописывания можно выполнить один раз, а не для каждой строки.

```
const string infile = @"D:\bzip2\decompressed.csv";
const string outfile = @"D:\bzip2\new.csv";
using (var in = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(infile))
using (var out = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(outfile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = in.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.Length >= 11)
            out.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Важный вопрос:

> цсв упрощенной формы, или же имеет "сложные ячейки" (которые имеют внутри ячейки делимитер/ переход на следующую строку)?

**Если таковые имеются, то твое решение НЕРАБОЧЕЕ.**

Как и советы даные мной ниже. Как и все другие ответы на даный момент.

---

## Мой ответ базируется на отсутствии сложных ячеек:

Тебе нужно сделать буфер чтения в виде нескольких мегабайт текста и обрабатывать именно этот текст.

Если ты делаешь построчно у тебя выходит слишком много операций чтения/записи совсем маленькими кусками. Из-за этого и медленная обработка.

Вот пример кода для чтения файла с буфером через стрим:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    }
}
```

код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643111/4423545)

Так же оптимизируй операцию записи. Запись для такого размера файла можно делать всего 1-2 раза за все время. Не обязательно аппендить все по каждому чиху.