# Оптимизация перебора элементов коллекции

Tags: c#

Имею программу, она в потоке читает `inTest.txt` файл, далее для каждого слова проводится `Trim()` и слова, длина которых `>= minWordLength` записываются в файл `outTest.txt`.

Метод чтения файла:

```
private static string ReadFromFileStream(FileStream inFileStream)
    {
            byte[] array = new byte[LENGTH];
            inFileStream.Read(array, 0, LENGTH);

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
    }
```

Метод записи в файл:

```
private static void WriteToFileStream(string text, string outFileName)
    {
        using (FileStream outFileStream = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) 
        {
            byte[] array = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
            outFileStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        }
    }
```

Действия с текстом:

```
private static string ProcessText(string text, int minWordLength, char[] charsToRemove)
    {
        string result = "";

        text.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(delegate(string word)
        {
            if (charsToRemove != null)
                word = word.Trim(charsToRemove);

            if (word.Length >= minWordLength)
                result += word + " ";
        });

        return result;
    }
```

`const int LENGTH = 1000000;`

С небольшими файлами проблем нет, но вот у меня тест на файле в 1ГБ. И скорость всего этого дела оставляет желать лучшего.

**Вопрос:** Возможно ли как то ускорить процесс?

Comment: [Читайте с буфером, пишите с буфером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947151/179763). Вообще сами строки большой длины? У вас может быть файл в гигабайт одной строкой?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, строки обычного размера, не больше 20 символов с учетом знаков препинания вокруг слова

Comment: тогда вам осталось скопировать код из ответа по моей ссылке все дела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала хотя бы используйте `StringBuilder` для накопления строк. Когда вы просто плюсуете строки каждый раз создаётся новая копия, это очень неоптимально.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
sb.Append(word);
sb.Append(" ");
...
sb.ToString();
```

Ну и буферизованный ввод-вывод файлов, конечно, тоже нужен.

Дальше можно ещё многопоточность припахать - один поток на чтение файла и помещение считанных строк в очередь, несколько потоков, которые будут эту очередь разгребать и преобразовывать строки, и ещё один поток, который будет записывать в новый файл. Самый оптимальный вариант, если вам не важен порядок строк на выходе, это будет быстрее всего. В противном случае придётся потоку записи иногда ждать очередную строку по порядку в буфере обработки.

Comment: `StringBuilder` не пригодится, если писать результат сразу в выходной поток с буфером. Многопоточность скорее всего тоже не пригодится, так как самые долгие операции тут - чтение и запись в файл, а не обрпботка строки.

Comment: @tym32167 В принципе да, но что такая штука есть надо всё-равно знать. Хотя всё-равно надо пробовать.

Comment: Звучит как хороший план, буду разбираться, читать. Спасибо