# Ускоренная обработка больших файлов

Tags: c#, шифрование, aes, обработка-данных

```
//string filename = "123.txt";
foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(pathToDesktopDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
using (var fsIn = new FileStream(files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var fsOut = new FileStream($"{files}.crypt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
using (var enc = aes.CreateEncryptor(new byte[16] /* ключ */, new byte[16] /* вектор */))
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsIn, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    cs.CopyTo(fsOut);
```

Большие файлы долго обрабатывает, прочёл что есть метод [MemoryMappedFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) который может обрабатывать большие файлы, подскажите как его можно использовать в коде выше??

Comment: Профилирование делали? Во что упираетесь: процессор или дисковую подсистему?

Comment: Насколько большие файлы? Пробовали читать и писать с буфером?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, больше упирается в дисковую подсистему.

Comment: @tym32167, Файлы большие от 1.5 гига до 4 гигов. Я вот сейчас пробую использовать с [System.Reactive.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh244252(v=vs.103))

Comment: [Работа с файлами большого объема C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947151/179763)

Comment: @tym32167, То есть мне за место `CryptoStream` нужно использовать `StreamWriter` ? немного не понял ( Как это реализовать в моём примере?

Comment: у вас есть файловые стримы, там и делайте буферизацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил немного буфера. Размер буфера подбирайте по своему разумению.

```
foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(pathToDesktopDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{   
    using (var fsIn = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), 10*1024*1024))
    using (var fsOut = new BufferedStream(new FileStream($"{files}.crypt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write), 10*1024*1024))
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    using (var enc = aes.CreateEncryptor(new byte[16] /* ключ */, new byte[16] /* вектор */))
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsIn, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        cs.CopyTo(fsOut);
}
```

Comment: А что вы можете сказать на счёт использования `Observable.Using` будет ли оно эффективнее ?

Comment: каким образом `Observable.Using` вообще связан с эффективностью?

Comment: @ZidoX реактивное не озачает быстрое. Мне в принципе не ясно, зачем вы на него обратили внимание, это не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме считывания файлов.